# CLLocationManager crashing app

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I'm working on a quite simple native extension for Adobe Air powered iOS app.

I'm playing with `CLLocationManager` class and i ran into really strange problem.

When i'm trying to initialize `CLRegion` object app crashes.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0);
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coords radius:100.0 identifier:@"Region1"];`
```

It doesn't look like it's a problem with the extension itself. It works fine, all other functionality works fine. Adding this bit of code is causing a problem.

Has anyone run into this problem as well?

UPDATE

it looks like i have problems with CLLocationManager as well... Sample code:

```
FREObject ExtensionTest(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject arg[]){
const char *str;

   if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable])
{
    str = "It works!";
}
else
{
    str = "No!";
}

FREObject retStr;
FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen(str)+1, (const uint8_t *)str, &retStr);

return retStr;
}
```

And that's what i get while tesing app on iphone 4 device...

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe1590002
Crashed Thread:  0

Comment: Please provide the error data; "crash" is rather vague.

Comment: you mean the whole device log entry?

Comment: No, just the last few lines that describes the problem, or a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Ensure you have specified the Apple iOS SDK correctly under the Native Extensions tab of your Apple iOS build packaging in your project settings. With default setup it should be...

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk